# What does square on matrix represent?

Tags: matrices

$$|A|\cdot |\tilde A|=1$$

Whereas $\tilde A=A^{-1}$ I had considered $|A| \cdot|\tilde A|$ as $A\tilde A$ so they are similarly $1$. But I had seen another equation

$$|A|^2=1$$

My question is what does the square is representing. I am taking $|A|$ as normal absolute value. But I wonder why square of a matrix is $0$. I believe if there's negative then that should be positive. They really can't cancel. Or they are taking something like $$|A|\cdot|A|=1$$ if that so than that make sense to me. I know that $1$ is unit matrix.

Comment: what is the normal absolute value for a matrix ?

Comment: To be honest no part of this question makes sense.

Comment: @Surb: I saw it being the determinant in some books. Quite a bad notation in my opinion.

Comment: @Taladris Ohh Yes You are correct I have seen that text now in that book..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a matrix $A$, the notation $|A|$ sometimes means the determinant of $A$.  With this notation $|A B| = |A| |B|$ for any matrices $A$ and $B$.  In particular $|A| |A^{-1}| = |A A^{-1}| = |I| = 1$.

Regarding the square: with this notation, if $A$ is a matrix such that $|A|^2 = 1$, then $|A| = \pm 1$, which means $A$ preserves volume but not necessarily orientation.  Does this help?

Comment: little bit but not sure if your idea is the correct one. But it makes sense. For that reason +1